# Jquery Visual Editor Suggestions

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface

Looking for a javascript editor similar to [ace](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace) which allows me to change the formatting of a simple page in the browser. The problem with ace is that it's outputting code, not rendered html.

I need to create something similar to the customise section on tumblr where a user can live update the theme of their blog. I.e. left panel contains controls and right panel contains preview.

As I'm totally new to this, can anyone recommend some decent ways / tools to do this?

Comment: take a look at  http://wooby.altervista.org/ Wooby visual programming is open source

Answer (score 1):

Sure I know one its [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) 
for in browser use you could use [nicedit](http://nicedit.com/)

Comment: I need less wysiwyg and more live visual editing. I.e. edit left pane, changes appear right hand. Including css change

Comment: Started writing it myself but realised someone must have done it better ;) Ace it fantastic but it's too techie for my users. They need visuals!

Comment: i need the same, i found one for wp called css hero , but then again, it is only for wp :( another one, payed service called bluepen , just google it